# Multiple routes to a destination using Bing REST

Tags: c#, bing-maps

Using this line results with only one path

```
Uri routeRequest = new Uri(string.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?wp.0={0}&wp.1={1}&rpo=Points&key={2}", 
                    from, to, MyMap.Credentials));
```

and so does this one

```
Uri routeRequest = new Uri(string.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Walking?wp.0={0}&wp.1={1}&rpo=Points&key={2}", 
                    from, to, MyMap.Credentials));
```

this one returns no results but it should return routes on major roads

```
Uri routeRequest = new Uri(string.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/FromMajorRoads?wp.0={0}&wp.1={1}&rpo=Points&key={2}", 
                    from, to, MyMap.Credentials));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the Bing Maps REST Routing service, the Major Routes functionality does not use waypoints like you are using them. Instead there is a destination parameter. You can find the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967514.aspx